# DTD for elements inside an element

Tags: xml, dtd

I need a DTD for validating an XML document like this:

```
<recipes>
     <recipe>
          <difficulty>2</difficulty>
          <people>4</people>
          <procedure>Break an egg and fry it</procedure>
          <ingredients>
               <ingredient>Egg</ingredient>
               <ingredient>...</ingredient>
          </ingredients>
     </recipe>
     ...
</recipes>
```

This is my DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT recipe(difficulty, people, procedure)>
<!ELEMENT difficulty #PCDATA>
<!ELEMENT people #PCDATA>
<!ELEMENT procedure #PCDATA>
```

which does not allow to declare `<ingredients>` element so that XML document would not be validated. How can I modify my DTD in order to achieve my goal?

My idea is:

```
<!ELEMENT recipe(difficulty, people, procedure, ingredients)>
<!ELEMENT difficulty #PCDATA>
<!ELEMENT people #PCDATA>
<!ELEMENT procedure #PCDATA>

<!ELEMENT ingredients(ingredient)>
<!ELEMENT ingredient #PCDATA>
```

but I am not sure this is the correct solution.

Comment: What is the problem in adding `ingredients` to the `recipe` line you have written there? What have you tried and what are the problems/error messages you get?

Comment: @Progman I have just edited my post with my possible solution but I am not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `+` operator to indicate, that you can have multiple elements of the same name inside another element. In this case it looks like this:

```
<!ELEMENT ingredients (ingredient+)>
<!ELEMENT ingredient (#PCDATA)>
```

The full DTD can look like this:

```
<!ELEMENT recipes (recipe+)>
<!ELEMENT recipe (difficulty, people, procedure, ingredients)>
<!ELEMENT difficulty (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT people (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT procedure (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ingredients (ingredient+)>
<!ELEMENT ingredient (#PCDATA)>
```